# Update matched key values in two JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My requirement is compare two objects and copy updated values into first object from second object.
Ex :

```
$scope.obj1={"id" : 1, "name" : "java"}
$scope.obj2={"id" : 1, "name" : "java4you", "gender" : "male"}

compare(destination, bj1, obj2);
```

Destination variable Output:

```
{"id" : 1, "name" : "java4you"}
```

The above two objects contains same keys but values are different. I have to compare obj1 and obj2 and update with matched obj2 values

Comment: You want to override and return properties with identical keys?

Comment: do you need to compare the ids before updating the "name" field? if not (the ids are always the same) you can do angular.extend(destination, obj1, obj2) which is a shallow copy. The output will be {"id" : 1, "name" : "java4you"}

Comment: Not quite @user4219031. `extend` will include `"gender":"male"`.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan  is correct if i use extend to copy the object properties "gender":"male" is also added to my destination object. I want to update only matched values in obj2 with obj1. I don't want additional key, value pairs which are not match with obj1.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy of `obj1` using `Object.assign()` in a new variable, `destination` and iterate through each key of `obj2` using `Object.keys()` and `array#forEach` and check if key exists in `destination`, in case it exists, update the value in `destination` from the value of `obj2`

```js
var obj1={"id" : 1, "name" : "java"},
    obj2={"id" : 1, "name" : "java4you", "gender" : "male"}

var updateObjectValue = (obj1, obj2) => {
  var destination = Object.assign({}, obj1);
  Object.keys(obj2).forEach(k => {
    if(k in destination) {
      destination[k] = obj2[k];
    }
  });
  return destination;
}
console.log(updateObjectValue(obj1, obj2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer is correct but in my case my json object contains huge number of elements. It is a combination of multiple inner objects and json arrays. It is not a good practice to loop such a big json object. Can you provide me any easy solution.

Comment: I would have recommended using `Object.assign()` but beside updating the value in object1, it will introduce all the remaining keys of `object2` which you might don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function compare(obj1, obj2)
{
    let obj = {};
    for(let k in obj1)
    {
         obj[k] = obj2[k];
     }
    return obj;
}
```

Usage should be like,

```
var destination = compare(obj1,obj2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The answers not familiar to my question. My requirement is not to compare two objects. Copy the matched key, values from second obj and update that key, value in  first object.

Comment: Then you can eliminate the comparison as updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Without actually referring to methods that can be used in angularJs, You can try this:**

```js
function compare(o1, o2) {
  var biggest = o1;
  
  if (Object.keys(o2).length > Object.keys(o1).length) {
    biggest = o2;
  }

 for (let key in biggest) {
   if (!biggest.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    
    if (o1[key] != o2[key]) {
     console.info("Difference in '"+ key +"': "+ o1[key] +" <> "+ o2[key]);
    }
 }
}

var $scope = {};

$scope.obj1 = {"id" : 1, "name" : "java"};
$scope.obj2 = {"id" : 1, "name" : "java4you", "gender" : "male"};

compare($scope.obj1, $scope.obj2);
```

But be careful using this, since it has many possible cases to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Using Angularjs, you can use .equal to compare and get the result, I don't see what is not working or providing your code will only gets you the answers.

```
$scope.result = angular.equals($scope.obj1, $scope.obj2);
if($scope.result === true){    
$scope.obj1 = $scope.obj2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to update @Bharadwaj answer for it to work for me.
   *for (... in ...) statements must be filtered with an if statement*

```js
    var obj1={"id" : 1, "name" : "java"},
        obj2={"id" : 1, "name" : "java4you", "gender" : "male"};

    function compare(obj1, obj2) {
      let obj = {};
      for(let k in obj1) {
         if(obj1[k] !== obj2[k]) {
           obj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj1[k] = obj2[k]);
         }
         
      }
      return obj;
    }
```